# Angular 404 Not Found regarding of the target URL

Tags: angular, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm currently working on an project with Angular/Spring. I have a problem on the Angular side.
I receive a 404 not found error no matter what. If it's get, put, for an employee, a provider, no matter, it will return a 404 not found error.
I need to add that I tested my endpoints in Postman, everything works fine, all of them.
Here are some classes that I think would help. If you need more information and code please ask right away and I will edit it in a very short time.
Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "csmart-front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^12.1.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Here I have a config json added at start when I run ng serve.

Proxy.conf.json:

```
{
  "/server": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/server": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my employee ts file. I don't have much on it, just a getAllEmployees method that should return my employees from the back-end and display them in a table:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeService } from 'src/app/service/employee.service';
import { Employee } from "../../interface/employee";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit
{
  employeeList: Employee[] = [];

  constructor(public employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void
  {
    this.employeeService.getAllEmployees().subscribe({
      next: employees => this.employeeList = employees,
      error: err => console.error(err)
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my employee service:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Employee } from "../interface/employee";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService
{
  private url = "server/employee/";

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    })
  }

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  getAllEmployees():Observable<Employee[]> { return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(this.url+'find/all'); }
}
```

And final but not least here is my app-routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './component/home/home.component';
import { EmployeeNewComponent } from './component/employee-new/employee-new.component';
import { EmployeeComponent } from './component/employee/employee.component';
import { EmployeeUpdateComponent } from './component/employee-update/employee-update.component';
import {ProviderComponent} from "./component/provider/provider.component";
import {ProviderNewComponent} from "./component/provider-new/provider-new.component";
import {ProviderUpdate} from "./component/provider-update/provider-update.component";
import {InvoiceinComponent} from "./component/invoicein/invoicein.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'home',
    component:HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'employees',
    component:EmployeeComponent
  },
  {
    path:'newEmployee',
    component:EmployeeNewComponent
  },
  {
    path:'editEmployee/:employeeId',
    component:EmployeeUpdateComponent
  },

  {
    path:'invoiceIns',
    component:InvoiceinComponent
  },

  {
    path:'providers',
    component:ProviderComponent
  },
  {
    path:'newProvider',
    component:ProviderNewComponent
  },
  {
    path:'editProvider/:providerId',
    component:ProviderUpdate
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[This is the error in browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl3oz.png)

Update: [I also attached the project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLFEN.png)

I can't see why this will return a 404 not found error no matter what. I used this before on an IntelliJ project that had the Ultimate version on it and it worked, the code is not changed, only the IDE because now I'm using Visual Studio Code. There is something extra that needs to be added here in order for my project to work or is my logic at fault?

IMPORTANT: as I said, no matter what is is: employee, provider, invoice etc. All of them are returing 404 not found regarding of the type of request (get, post, delete etc).

Thank you and if this needs more resources please let me know and I will edit the post.

Comment: what if you change the PORT in the proxy target from 8080 to 4200 ?

Comment: @CCBet Nope, I tried now. Still the same error. That should be ok from what I'm guessing. The port of the app in Spring is 8080 so that is his target.

Comment: Just for test, try to change your requisition to:

---------

  getAllEmployees():Observable<Employee[]> { 
     return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>('http://localhost:8080/' + this.url+'find/all'); 
  }

-----------

Looking in the image of the error, the requisition is not going to the backend.

Comment: Looking at the error log, your proxy isn't used. How do you serve the application? just by running `ng serve`? You should use `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` or `npm run start` as defined in your package.json. Also make sure the proxy.config.json is located in the root folder of your project.

Comment: @PriscilaAnjos I tried, still not working

Comment: @W.S. I used ng serve at first. I also tried with npm run start and the terminal executed the proxy config as well, but the error is still the same. I also updated the post and provided a screenshot with my project tree.

Comment: Try with a forward slash in front of the url `private url = "/server/employee/";`? If your backend server application is running on port `8080`, and you still see the requests going to `4200` the proxy isn't used. Then a 404 is normal behaviour.

Comment: @W.S. I don't have any clue how but that / worked... Somehow using /server/employee instead of server/employee saved the day... Thank you! I don't understand why it worked, but it did.

Comment: In your proxy config you ask to intercept all routes starting with `/server`, so if you don't prefix it, the proxy doesn't intercept. You're welcome!

Comment: @W.S. Aaaa... Now I get it... I thought that the / at the start is not mandatory and won't affect my application behaviour in any way, my bad. Thank you and happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serve the application through

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

and prefix your urls with a forward slash as defined in your `proxy.config.json`

```
private url = "/server/employee/";
```